Node.js Electron - read https
I am writing a program for a PC on Windows 10 OS using node.js and Electron.
I need to communicate with a site on SSL, which works on a certificate of the new Russian certification center from the Ministry of Digitalization (минцифры). This center is not included in Node.js, but added to Windows OS.
Node.js does not use system certificates, so I can not connect to the site.
I use axios() in main.js.
Maybe someone knows how to do this?
Typical advice for Node.js does not work here:

I am not creating a site on SSL or server, I want to read someone else's site.
I do not have a key, because I am not the owner of the certificate.
Electron blocks openssl flags. In addition, this is Windows - openssl does not work in it.
The certificate has a limited lifetime, and my program must be forever. Therefore, the options with installing certificates are not suitable at all.

The certification authority provides two files for Windows OS:

russian_trusted_root_ca.cer
russian_trusted_sub_ca.cer
I have no idea what they contain, but I assume that these must be public certificates that everyone has.
I assume they include the certification authority in the list of trusted ones.

I have never worked with certificates and do not want to start.
So far, the best solution I see is to completely disable certificate checking.
I don't like it, but I don't see any other options.
Hypothetically, there is a library "win-ca"
https://github.com/ukoloff/win-ca/tree/master
It should connect Node.js with the certificate database in the Windows system.
There are probably other similar libraries.
In practice, this is an even bigger security hole than simply disabling certificate checking: the probability that someone will covet my traffic and try to extract my favorite key from there is extremely small and is approximately equal to the probability that a meteorite will hit me. But to introduce into the system an unknown code that will poke around in the security settings of the entire OS, written by anonymous people unknown to me... I don't know what could be worse.
In addition, this puts an end to cross-system compatibility - my program will be forever tied to the Windows OS. And this is also a security problem in the modern world - who knows what will come to their minds in a couple of years.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
